# rails activerecord belongs_to problem - can't insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to

Seems simple, but having an issue:

```
model A
belong_to :B

model B
has_many :A

database tables:
table A:
id,...,b_id

table B:
id,...
```

When trying to create a new A, I set (an existing) B by doing:
a.b = B

I get an error saying "b can't be blank"

Comment: As a thought to bear in mind for future SO questions, you might want to call your example tables something slightly less confusing than "B" and "A" to make responses easier to read and easier to write.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the feedback. I was using A and B so that I don't get responses like "persons should be people".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a.b = B, do a.b_id = B.id.

Comment: when I did this, it say "Bs (plural) can not be null"

Comment: Then there's something really wrong with your code as you're saving A and getting an error from B.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how your collection and parent-child relationships work. You can -as suggested- add the ID of the relevant B to your A, but you may alternatively want to say  `B.a[] = a` which would add "a" to your the "a" collection of your object "B". That way the relationship is set up in a more intuitive way, oriented towards the parent object rather than the child.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do `newA = B.as.build` ('as' being the plural of a).

Of course your examples of 'A, a, B and b` are very confusing! In the future use 'customer' & 'order' or 'blog' & 'post' or *anything* but cryptic letters with no meaning.

Comment: Noted. Like I said above, I didn't want to get responses regarding pluralizing. I will keep this in mind for the future